# Open Form to a value selected on ComboBox - Ms Acces

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, vba

I want to open a form to a specific record based on the value is selected on a comboBox. I have written a code and its working, but before opening the form it shows a dialogue box with input field asking for the parameter i want for the form which i dont want the VB code to ask.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Final_Exam", acNormal, , "[admclass] = " & Me.Combo4.Value & ""
```

This is the code i have written and the requirement is that on clicking the button the form opens without any dialogue box asking for parameter.  thanksa

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is the best way to open one form from another is to use `OpenArgs`. When opening Form 2 from Form 1's button, use code like this:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenOtherForm_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmOtherForm", OpenArgs:=Me.Combo4.Value
End Sub
```

Then, in the `Load` event of Form 2, use the `openargs` to set up your filter:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.Filter="[admclass]=""" & Me.OpenArgs & """"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If the field you're filtering on is a text field, make sure to properly escape double quotes (as is done above).